# C# : To use IndexOutOfRangeException or to avoid it?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I have a 2D array (image) and I am always checking the boundary of index in a function like:

```
...
if (y < 0)
  return -1;
if (x < 0)
  return -1;
if (y >= width)
  return -1;
if (x >= height)
  return -1;

int col = imgArray[y,x];
return col;
```

I would like to change this code like this:

```
...
int col = -1;

try {
    col = imgArray[y,x];
}
catch (IndexOutOfRangeException ex) {
    return -1;
}
```

To make compiler check the boundary, instead of me myself.

Is it an appropriate way to use Exceptions to help coding?
Otherwise, should Exceptions be avoid all the time as possible as I can?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/189225/132348 but there are many proponents for and opponents to using exceptions in control flow, so this question is too opinion-based for SO.

Comment: I can assure you that checking and catching exceptions to help with code is perfectly accepted.

Comment: You may use extension method: `public static bool IsInRange<T>(this T[,] arr, int x, int y) => x >= 0 && x < arr.Length && y >= 0 && y < arr.Rank;` then in your code `var col = imgArray.IsInRange(y, x) ? imgArray[y, x] : -1;`

Comment: The question seams to lead to bit broader subject. What a hypothetical caller is supposed to do with -1 value? Will it throw new exception or will log the result or will simply ignore? The answer to your question may depend on this factors as if you need more detailed information on higher levels it would better to provide of information what piece of data caused the problem which is typically done with arguments verification.

Comment: I'd object to doing this in the first place. If you are iterating over your image, you'd have 4 additional comparisons per pixel. I'd expect a significant performance impact at least on large images. Check boundaries one time before you enter your iteration.

Comment: In my opinion, exceptions are something that the callee can tell the caller "That's not my fault because I did not cause it, but predicted it, so the problem must not be inside my code,", so if the argument passed to your code is directly passed to others' code, let it throw exception, then catch it (as inner exception), warp it (as inner exception), and throw your own exception.

Comment: The key point is that, exceptions are exceptions, which is something wrong, therefore you would never intend to cause any exception, unless there already is, caused from extern. And the purpose of throwing exception is converting problems from implicit and unexpected behavior to explained and reported issue.